# How do I remove the truncation in my vim-airline status bar

Tags: vim, vim-airline

I have vim set up with vim-airline and powerline. My problem is that my statusbar is truncated in the z-section. It appears that my column number is hidden behind some symbol and this persists even if I resize the terminal.

[image]

I have tried formatting the z-section like this:

```
function! AirlineInit()
    call airline#parts#define_raw('linenr', '%l')
    call airline#parts#define_accent('linenr', 'bold')
    let g:airline_section_z = airline#section#create(['%3p%% ', g:airline_symbols.linenr, 'linenr', ':%c  !'])
endfunction
autocmd VimEnter * call AirlineInit()
```

adding whitespaces followed by a character (in this case '!'). In that case the status bar will expand, but only after I have resized the terminal. This does not work if I only put in whitespaces, they need to be followed by a non-whitespace character for it to work.

[image]

How do I fix this?

My `.vimrc`:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
"   Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
" Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
"   Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
"   Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
" The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
" Pass the path to set the runtimepath promerly.
"   Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" Install L9 and avoid a Naming conflict if you've already installed a
" different version somewhere else.
"   Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}

Plugin 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'catppuccin/vim'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Maintainer:
"       Amir Salihefendic — @amix3k
"
" Awesome_version:
"       Get this config, nice color schemes and lots of plugins!
"
"       Install the awesome version from:
"
"           https://github.com/amix/vimrc
"
" Sections:
"    -> General
"    -> VIM user interface
"    -> Colors and Fonts
"    -> Files and backups
"    -> Text, tab and indent related
"    -> Visual mode related
"    -> Moving around, tabs and buffers
"    -> Status line
"    -> Editing mappings
"    -> vimgrep searching and cope displaying
"    -> Spell checking
"    -> Misc
"    -> Helper functions
"
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => General
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Shows line numbers
set number

" Sets how many lines of history VIM has to remember
set history=500

" Enable filetype plugins
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

" Set to auto read when a file is changed from the outside
set autoread
au FocusGained,BufEnter * checktime

" With a map leader it's possible to do extra key combinations
" like <leader>w saves the current file
let mapleader = ","

" Fast saving
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>

" :W sudo saves the file
" (useful for handling the permission-denied error)
command! W execute 'w !sudo tee % > /dev/null' <bar> edit!


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => VIM user interface
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Set 7 lines to the cursor - when moving vertically using j/k
set so=7

" Avoid garbled characters in Chinese language windows OS
let $LANG='en'
set langmenu=en
source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim

" Turn on the Wild menu
set wildmenu

" Ignore compiled files
set wildignore=*.o,*~,*.pyc
if has("win16") || has("win32")
    set wildignore+=.git\*,.hg\*,.svn\*
else
    set wildignore+=*/.git/*,*/.hg/*,*/.svn/*,*/.DS_Store
endif

" Always show current position
set ruler

" Height of the command bar
set cmdheight=1

" A buffer becomes hidden when it is abandoned
set hid

" Configure backspace so it acts as it should act
set backspace=eol,start,indent
set whichwrap+=<,>,h,l

" Ignore case when searching
set ignorecase

" When searching try to be smart about cases
set smartcase

" Highlight search results
set hlsearch

" Makes search act like search in modern browsers
set incsearch

" Don't redraw while executing macros (good performance config)
set lazyredraw

" For regular expressions turn magic on
set magic

" Show matching brackets when text indicator is over them
set showmatch

" How many tenths of a second to blink when matching brackets
set mat=2

" No annoying sound on errors
set noerrorbells
set novisualbell
set t_vb=
set tm=500

" Properly disable sound on errors on MacVim
if has("gui_macvim")
    autocmd GUIEnter * set vb t_vb=
endif

" Add a bit extra margin to the left
set foldcolumn=1


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Colors and Fonts
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Enable syntax highlighting
syntax enable

" Enable 256 colors palette in Gnome Terminal
if $COLORTERM == 'gnome-terminal'
    set t_Co=256
endif

set termguicolors
try
    colorscheme catppuccin_mocha
catch
endtry

" Enable the list of buffers
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1

let g:airline_skip_empty_sections = 1

" air-line
let g:airline_theme = 'catppuccin_mocha'
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
     let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" unicode symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = '»'
let g:airline_left_sep = '▶'
let g:airline_right_sep = '«'
let g:airline_right_sep = '◀'
let g:airline_symbols.colnr = ' ℅:'
let g:airline_symbols.crypt = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '☰'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ' ␊:'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ' ␤:'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '¶'
let g:airline_symbols.maxlinenr = ''
let g:airline_symbols.maxlinenr = '㏑'
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '⎇'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'ρ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'Þ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = '∥'
let g:airline_symbols.spell = 'Ꞩ'
let g:airline_symbols.notexists = 'Ɇ'
let g:airline_symbols.whitespace = 'Ξ'

" airline symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '☰'
let g:airline_symbols.maxlinenr = ''
let g:airline_symbols.dirty='⚡'

set background=dark

" Set extra options when running in GUI mode
if has("gui_running")
    set guioptions-=T
    set guioptions-=e
    set t_Co=256
    set guitablabel=%M\ %t
endif

" Set utf8 as standard encoding and en_US as the standard language
set encoding=utf8

" Use Unix as the standard file type
set ffs=unix,dos,mac


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Files, backups and undo
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Turn backup off, since most stuff is in SVN, git etc. anyway...
set nobackup
set nowb
set noswapfile


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Text, tab and indent related
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Use spaces instead of tabs
set expandtab

" Be smart when using tabs ;)
set smarttab

" 1 tab == 4 spaces
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4

" Linebreak on 500 characters
set lbr
set tw=500

set ai "Auto indent
set si "Smart indent
set wrap "Wrap lines


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Visual mode related
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Visual mode pressing * or # searches for the current selection
" Super useful! From an idea by Michael Naumann
vnoremap <silent> * :<C-u>call VisualSelection('', '')<CR>/<C-R>=@/<CR><CR>
vnoremap <silent> # :<C-u>call VisualSelection('', '')<CR>?<C-R>=@/<CR><CR>


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Moving around, tabs, windows and buffers
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Map <Space> to / (search) and Ctrl-<Space> to ? (backwards search)
map <space> /
map <C-space> ?

" Disable highlight when <leader><cr> is pressed
map <silent> <leader><cr> :noh<cr>

" Smart way to move between windows
map <C-j> <C-W>j
map <C-k> <C-W>k
map <C-h> <C-W>h
map <C-l> <C-W>l

" Close the current buffer
map <leader>bd :Bclose<cr>:tabclose<cr>gT

" Close all the buffers
map <leader>ba :bufdo bd<cr>

map <leader>l :bnext<cr>
map <leader>h :bprevious<cr>

" Useful mappings for managing tabs
map <leader>tn :tabnew<cr>
map <leader>to :tabonly<cr>
map <leader>tc :tabclose<cr>
map <leader>tm :tabmove
map <leader>t<leader> :tabnext

" Let 'tl' toggle between this and the last accessed tab
let g:lasttab = 1
nmap <Leader>tl :exe "tabn ".g:lasttab<CR>
au TabLeave * let g:lasttab = tabpagenr()


" Opens a new tab with the current buffer's path
" Super useful when editing files in the same directory
map <leader>te :tabedit <C-r>=expand("%:p:h")<cr>/

" Switch CWD to the directory of the open buffer
map <leader>cd :cd %:p:h<cr>:pwd<cr>

" Specify the behavior when switching between buffers
try
  set switchbuf=useopen,usetab,newtab
  set stal=2
catch
endtry

" Return to last edit position when opening files (You want this!)
au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Status line
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Always show the status line
set laststatus=2

" Format the status line
set statusline=\ %{HasPaste()}%F%m%r%h\ %w\ \ CWD:\ %r%{getcwd()}%h\ \ \ Line:\ %l\ \ Column:\ %c


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Editing mappings
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Remap VIM 0 to first non-blank character
map 0 ^

" Move a line of text using ALT+[jk] or Command+[jk] on mac
nmap <M-j> mz:m+<cr>`z
nmap <M-k> mz:m-2<cr>`z
vmap <M-j> :m'>+<cr>`<my`>mzgv`yo`z
vmap <M-k> :m'<-2<cr>`>my`<mzgv`yo`z

if has("mac") || has("macunix")
  nmap <D-j> <M-j>
  nmap <D-k> <M-k>
  vmap <D-j> <M-j>
  vmap <D-k> <M-k>
endif

" Delete trailing white space on save, useful for some filetypes ;)
fun! CleanExtraSpaces()
    let save_cursor = getpos(".")
    let old_query = getreg('/')
    silent! %s/\s\+$//e
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
    call setreg('/', old_query)
endfun

if has("autocmd")
    autocmd BufWritePre *.txt,*.js,*.py,*.wiki,*.sh,*.coffee :call CleanExtraSpaces()
endif


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Spell checking
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Pressing ,ss will toggle and untoggle spell checking
map <leader>ss :setlocal spell!<cr>

" Shortcuts using <leader>
map <leader>sn ]s
map <leader>sp [s
map <leader>sa zg
map <leader>s? z=


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Misc
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Remove the Windows ^M - when the encodings gets messed up
noremap <Leader>m mmHmt:%s/<C-V><cr>//ge<cr>'tzt'm

" Quickly open a buffer for scribble
map <leader>q :e ~/buffer<cr>

" Quickly open a markdown buffer for scribble
map <leader>x :e ~/buffer.md<cr>

" Toggle paste mode on and off
map <leader>pp :setlocal paste!<cr>


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Helper functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Returns true if paste mode is enabled
function! HasPaste()
    if &paste
        return 'PASTE MODE  '
    endif
    return ''
endfunction

" Don't close window, when deleting a buffer
command! Bclose call <SID>BufcloseCloseIt()
function! <SID>BufcloseCloseIt()
    let l:currentBufNum = bufnr("%")
    let l:alternateBufNum = bufnr("#")

    if buflisted(l:alternateBufNum)
        buffer #
    else
        bnext
    endif

    if bufnr("%") == l:currentBufNum
        new
    endif

    if buflisted(l:currentBufNum)
        execute("bdelete! ".l:currentBufNum)
    endif
endfunction

function! CmdLine(str)
    call feedkeys(":" . a:str)
endfunction

function! VisualSelection(direction, extra_filter) range
    let l:saved_reg = @"
    execute "normal! vgvy"

    let l:pattern = escape(@", "\\/.*'$^~[]")
    let l:pattern = substitute(l:pattern, "\n$", "", "")

    if a:direction == 'gv'
        call CmdLine("Ack '" . l:pattern . "' " )
    elseif a:direction == 'replace'
        call CmdLine("%s" . '/'. l:pattern . '/')
    endif

    let @/ = l:pattern
    let @" = l:saved_reg
endfunction
```

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker?